# Error 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, nginx

I uploaded a phpinfo page to my website root and I gave it full ownership and I'm using nginx and my nginx error log is giving me this:

```
2017/05/08 15:01:48 [error] 17024#0: *998370 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.com, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "website.com"
```

But I don't know where the rules are set. I checked /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and I didn't see anything where it showed deny or anything similar so I'm not sure how to fix this

UPDATE: Here is my nginx configuration file and these are the relevant parts that might be causing this issue

```
# Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }


# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

How can I edit these rules so I can allow phpinfo.php only?

UPDATE #2: I updated the rules and now instead of the 404 page not found error I'm getting a redirect to my magento website and this is fine for everything else but I'm just trying to view the phpinfo.php without being redirected or blocked

Comment: Most probably your config is intentionally blocking it, paste it here also

Comment: @bodi0 I updated my post to include what I believe is the relevant info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I believe in this line, here the configuration denies execution of.php files (more specifically the rule `\.php$|`:

```
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
deny all;
}
```

Remove the rule, keep however the others, regarding htaccess and git.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit it so I can allow phpinfo.php only?

Comment: Of course you can edit the config, if you have access to the file with write permissions... Also you can change the rule to (!phpinfo\.php$|\.php$)

Comment: Sorry change which rule from the 2 I posted? And I updated my post but I need to turn off the redirect for this phpinfo.php file only